# Speed of electrons in a wire

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, electric-current, conductors

What is the speed of electrons in a copper wire, used to charge a device? If there is a fixed speed, how is it determined?

Comment: So where have you looked yourself regarding electron  speeds?

Comment: Search for drift velocity

Comment: I think OP is concerned about the speed of a signal thru a copper wire. But maybe I'm wrong. I answered that specific question but deleted it because it wasn't worded well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point in speaking about the "speed of an electron in a copper wire". You may ask the ***drift velocity*** of the electron under an applied potential. The electrons are randomly scattered by phonons (lattice vibrations) as well as the metal ions. Under an applied field, in addition to the *thermal random motion*, the electron moves from region of negative potential to the region of positive potential *with an average velocity*, a motion which is known as **drift**. The drift velocity of an electron is very low: about $1 mm/s$. However, the Fermi velocity is as higher as several ten or hundred thousands of meters per second for a metal. The drift velocity of an electron in a metal is given by

$$v_{d}=\frac{eE\tau}{m}$$

where $e$ is the electronic charge, $m$ is the electron rest mass, $E$ is the applied electric field and $\tau$ is the relaxation time.

> To know the drift velocity of electrons in copper, all you have to do is just *measure the resistance of copper*.

Then the conductivity of copper is given by

$$\sigma=\frac{l}{RA}$$

where $R$ is the resistance of the copper wire, $l$ and $A$ are the length and cross-sectional area of the wire. If the applied potential difference across the length of the wire is $V$, then the electric field can be approximated as

$$E=\frac{V}{l}$$

Now, the Fermi velocity of copper can be found out if you know the Fermi energy of copper ($7.00 eV$):

$$v_F=\sqrt{\frac{2E_F}{m}}$$

Next, you need the mean free path length, which is given by

$$\lambda=\frac{mv_F\sigma}{ne^2}$$

where, $n$ is the electron density in copper, and is given by

$$n=\frac{N_A\rho}{A}$$

where, $N_A$ is the Avogadro number, $\rho$ is the density of copper and $A$ is its atomic weight. Knowing $\lambda$, you can calculate the relaxation time as

$$\tau=\frac{\lambda}{v_F}$$

Substitute all these results in the first expression and you are done.

> Note:
>
> 1. This is an experimental way of doing the job. Standard values are available on textbooks and internet.
> 2. Caution: Use a very long copper wire (10 m or above) or use mV range potential. The current density of copper is very large.